# How to execute different actions every time the text gets switched?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have some simple code that switches some text when an `iBeacon` gets close to an iOS client:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        if detector.lastDistance == .immediate{
            return Text("close!")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.green)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    busStatus(text: "close!");
                    vibrate()
                })
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .near{
            return Text("near")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.green)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    busStatus(text: "near!")
                })
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .far{
            return Text("far")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.green)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    busStatus(text: "far!")
                })
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else {
            return Text("no data")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.red)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    busStatus(text: "no data!")
                })
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, when I execute the code, `"no data!"` gets spoken, however, when I move the beacon closer, the text changes and the color goes green, however the `busStatus` function (text to voice) does not run, neither does my vibrate function.

Is this a design issue with how I am writing this?

Comment: onAppear is related to the lifecycle of the current screen, just like viewDidAppear in UIKit. It will be triggered for embedded components like the Text here only when the whole screen appears, not the component itself

Comment: Thanks for the comment, then what would you recommend for my use case? This is my first test project in swift so I am a bit inexperienced when it comes to knowing what it has to offer.

Comment: is your `detector` a ObservableObject and the `lastDistance` property is `@Published`?

Comment: Yes, they are properly handled :)

Comment: alternatively to the already posted solution, you could use [onReceive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:)) and pass the `$lastDistance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many duplications... it's really needed to be refactored into separated model type to have something like

```
@State private var status: CLProximity = .unknown

var body: some View {
    Text(status.text)
        .modifier(BigText())
        .background(status.color)
        .onChange(of: status) {
            busStatus(text: $0.spoken)
            if $0 == .immediate {
               vibrate()
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

and new type (with corresponding initializer from underline API)

```
extension CLProximity {

  var text: String {
    switch self {
      case .immediate:
        return "close!"
      case .near:
        return "near"
      case .far:
        return "far"
      default:
        return "no data"
    }
  }

  var spoken: String {
    switch self {
      case .immediate:
        return "close!"
      case .near:
        return "near!"
      case .far:
        return "far!"
      default:
        return "no data!"
    }
  }

  var color: Color {
    switch self {
      case .immediate, .near, .far:
        return .green
      default:
        return .red
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely a dumb question, I tried to update BusStatus with `BusStatus = detector.lastDistance` but obviously it didn't work. How would I go about doing this? Detector is an @ObservedObject

Comment: Obviously, you just need to adapt `lastDistance` to be a `BusStatus`.

Comment: Sorry I understand what you mean, but I have no clue where to begin. I tried just setting it to lastDistance but received an `Cannot use instance member 'detector' within property initializer` error. I'm a bit confused because I just use lastDistance and compare it to .near, but I cannot set it to BusStatus.

Comment: ok, if your `lastDistance` is-a `CLProximity` then see updated with extension to it. If you do not provide code with all dependent parts be prepared to take responsibility for adapting provided answers to your code.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize at first that the issue would involve those parts. Right now it compiles after adding the extension and changing the body but the state seems to be not updating. Is there something else that I am missing? How should I use detector.lastDistance now to update CLProximity?

Comment: I was tweaking around with some code and realized if I changed the code to `.onChange(of: detector.lastDistance)` the audio would update but the text wouldn't.

Comment: Solved! Just changed status to lastDistance, thank you :)